# jQuery Quadratic equations

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whats wrong in my code for solving jQuery Quadratic equations ?

```
a = parseFloat($('#a').val());
b = parseFloat($('#b').val());
c = parseFloat($('#c').val());
root = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c));
x1 = (-b + root) / 2 * a;
x2 = (-b - root) / 2 * a;

function validateForm(){
            $('#result1').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#result2').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#result1').html('First ans equal' + x1);
            $('#result2').html('Second ans equal' + x2);
}
```

Maybe its the root, or the POW ? Help me to figure this out please

Comment: As a note, you can combine your `.fadeIn()` methods into one statement: `$('#result1, #result2').fadeIn('slow');`. Is the JavaScript console giving you any errors?

Comment: what happens when this code runs? do you get an error? can you provide an example using jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm getting 'Not a Number' (NaN) for this code.  Are you seeing the same?

Comment: Ah, yes, the answer below explains why - I was rooting a negative number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its simple maths. jQuery/Javascript has very little to contribute in this.

**for the jquery/Javascript part:**

make sure `#a, #b,#c` have values when you run your code. i.e.

```
 $('#a').val() = some valid Float text
```

one thing you can do in this regard is to wrap your variables `a,b,c` inside a function.

and call the function on some button click or only after you're sure that `#a`,`#b`,`#c` have value.

see below illustration:

```
var x1,x2;
function calculate(){

     a = parseFloat($('#a').val());
     b = parseFloat($('#b').val());
     c = parseFloat($('#c').val());

     root = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c));

     x1 = (-b + root) / 2 * a;
     x2 = (-b - root) / 2 * a;
}

$('#validate').on("click",function(){
     calculate();
    $('.result').html('').append('first answer'+x1).append('second answer'+x2);
});
```

**Maths Part**.

It will work fine as long as your quadratic equation has rational roots. i.e. if you give your
`coefficients(a,b,c)` a value, that your quadratic equation has no rational roots, in that case you will get `NaN` in your x1 and x2, because the result that you get are not Real Numbers but a Complex Number.

so everytime `Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c) < 0`, you are not going to get any real roots i.e. you will get NaN inside x1 and x2

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zKGxF/)